# IBM Watson Assistant service call returning 404 error message

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I am using this code to call my watson assistant service but getting 404 error message

```
IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator(apiKey);
Assistant assistant = new Assistant(version, authenticator);
assistant.setServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
CreateSessionOptions options = new CreateSessionOptions.Builder(assistantId).build();
assistant.createSession(options);
SessionResponse response = assistant.createSession(options).execute().getResult();
```

I got the URL,apiKey, and assistantId from **assistant settings->Assistant IDs and API details**

I am not sure what I am missing any idea???

I tried the URL with curl, soapui but nothing is working same error 404

Comment: I assume that you set the variables accordingly. Add details on how you used curl. What was the URL? What parameters did you specify?

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 normally means you have `ServiceUrl` or `Assistant_id` incorrect.

Check the following.

1. That your URL is pointing to the right instance Geo. Go to your assistant settings and you will find the URL. [More details](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#service-endpoint) on how to find this:
2. Check that your `assistant_id` is correct. From the [API documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#message).

> The assistant ID or the environment ID of the environment where the
> assistant is deployed, depending on the type of request:
>
> - For message, session, and log requests, specify the environment ID of the environment where the assistant is deployed.
> - For all other requests, specify the assistant ID of the assistant.
>
> To find the environment ID or assistant ID in the Watson Assistant
> user interface, open the assistant settings and scroll to the
> Environments section.
>
> Note: If you are using the classic Watson Assistant experience, always
> use the assistant ID. To find the assistant ID in the user interface,
> open the assistant settings and click API Details.